What exactly is the implausibility and unconvincingness of solipsism?
Solipsism is unconvincing and implausible because it is a complex and confusing explanation.

Solipsism offers two different explanations for no reason at all: one for my behavior and one for other people's behavior.

This makes solipsism a more complex and confusing explanation.
The existence of other minds offers a single explanation for my behavior and the behavior of other people.
This makes the existence of other minds a simple and straightforward explanation.

Solipsism says that only I have a mind, and other people who are very similar to me and whose behavior is very similar to mine do not have minds.

This explanation is complicated and confusing because it makes me special among other people for no reason at all.

Solipsism says that only my mind exists and that all people are created by my mind and exist only for me to interact with them. That is, all people and the whole world were created by my mind just for me.

It's also a complicated and confusing explanation because it also makes me special for no reason at all.

But if we consider the scenario in which I am in the world created by the mind.

And in this world, other people have no minds.
Other people are also created by the mind.
But this is not my mind.
In this case, I will no longer be special because other people and the surrounding world were not created by my mind and not for me.
Where in this explanation are implausible and unconvincing statements?
Help me figure this out.
Also, please explain if I made any mistakes in my explanations.
Thank you very much.

All this misses the key point: There is something very unique to your experience of you being you. Something completely unexplainable, unshareable, indescribable. See What is it like to be a bat. It is a fact that the verb to be is not just irregular in English but is regularly irregular in a slew of languages. Eg He is, you are, I am. Compare with any other verb sit, talk, eat...

I mean unique among other people and unique because self-centered.Please explain why solipsism is implausible and unconvincing?

I find it implausible and unconvincing, and that is all that matters.

I'm not sure who or what you are arguing against here. I think you're probably right that solipsism's explanatory power is rather limited compared to non-solipsistic views. But that is not controversial: I have never encountered solipsism functioning in a philosophical work as an "explanation" for anything. ...

... Rather, it is usually used as a metric for a reductio-ad-absurdum: if your theory entails solipsism, then your theory is faulty. No one seriously considers solipsism as a philosophical option. Wittgenstein maybe comes closest, but he never applies it as an explanatory device, rather, he mentions in the context of a discussion of the limits of scientific explanation.

Please explain what explanatory power means. I can't quite understand what it looks like. I understand what explanatory simplicity is, but what is explanatory power? Can you show what the explanatory power of the existence of other minds looks like and what the explanatory power of solipsism looks like. And why is the explanatory power of solipsism worse?

Here is the thing I dislike about solipsism: someone else thought of it first.

If you argue in favour of solipcism with others, you've already lost.

OP: "Where in this explanation are implausible and unconvincing statements?"

Solipsism says that only my mind exists

Your mind has been cultivated by interaction with others and immersion in culture since birth, so it is not an island. A child may initially assume that it actually is the whole world and later develops an appreciation of separate identities, but the idea that "this bit is mine to look after" does not mean that your mind is all your own product.  Your mind is produced with others, in, as Heidegger puts it in Being & Time, a "with-world".

¶ 26. The Dasein-with of Others and Everyday Being-with
. . . Thus in characterizing the encountering of Others, one is again
still oriented by that Dasein which is in each case one's own. But
even in this characterization does one not start by marking out and
isolating the 'I' so that one must then seek some way of getting over
to the Others from this isolated subject? To avoid this
misunderstanding we must notice in what sense we are talking about
'the Others'. By 'Others' we do not mean everyone else but me—those
over against whom the "I" stands out. They are rather those from whom,
for the most part, one does not distinguish oneself—those among whom
one is too. This Being-there-too [Auch-da­-sein] with them does not
have the ontological character of a
Being-present­-at-hand-along-'with' them within a world. This 'with'
is something of the character of Dasein; the 'too' means a sameness of
Being as circumspectively concernful Being-in-the-world. 'With' and
'too' are to be understood existentially, not categorially. By
reason of this with-like [mithaften] Being-in-the-world, the world
is always the one that I share with Others. The world of Dasein is a
with-world [Mitwelt].


Please explain why solipsism is not convincing and implausible?

@Arnold Because your mind is not an island.

Please explain point 4. I don't understand how to explain implausibility and unconvincingness in this case.

@Arnold "consider the scenario in which I am in the world created by the mind". So you are everybody else too. This view doesn't change anything about the world.

But this suggests that only I have a mind and other people do not have minds.Where exactly is implausibility and unconvincingness here?

@Arnold So you are dreaming everything, like in the Chuang Tzu : "you do not know whether we that are now speaking are awake or in a dream. ... When one rests in what has been arranged, and puts away all thought of the transformation, he is in unity with the mysterious Heaven.'"

I wish we had a better explanation than the words of someone who sounds like they have schizophrenia. Can't anyone do better than that? After all this time?

@ScottRowe My take is after Heidegger the deconstructionists came and exposed the shifting sands of meaning and the pragmatists said meaning is whatever works, so they kind of gave up on big system philosophy.

Well, I hope that if during the Olympics all the runners gave up, they wouldn't still call it a race or award any medals. Not doing something is not doing it. So to speak.

@ScottRowe hear hear! Why oh why do people perpetuate the meaningless blather spouted by the likes of Heidegger. FFS.

@MarcoOcram The main theme in Heidegger is the meaning of Being—which from Ch. 1 is understood as 'indefinable' (Der Begriff »Sein« ist undefinierbar.)—and the extensive delineation of Dasein is only in order to bring that into focus. There's a nice quote from Pascal on the linked page, which addresses the meaninglessness and indefinability of existence: "...  Donc pour définir l’être, il faudrait dire c’est, et ainsi employer le mot défini dans sa définition."

In defining existence one must say "it is such and such" and therefore use the term being defined in its own definition, which is invalid. This is because existence is the top level genre. definitio fit per genus proximum et differentiam specificam. "This rule which follows Aristotle, according to which a definition must be made by specifying the next higher genre and the specific difference, was canonical to the traditional logic of the nineteenth century."

And on down the rabbit-hole.

@ChrisDegnen cheers! I agree that it is impossible to put fundamental ideas into words without presupposing what the words mean. I remember some old ideas I had about learning physics. It struck me that you could develop an understanding of some aspects of physics by building conceptual models out of simpler building blocks, rather like building with lego blocks. However, you need to recognise that there are some shapes you can't build with your existing lego blocks, and what you need is a fundamentally new type of  lego block that is not reducible to the others...

...and there's a parallel with aspects of philosophy. You have to accept that there are certain conceptual building blocks, or primitives, that can't be expressed in terms of anything more fundamental without going round in circles.

@MarcoOcram Indeed I see this indeterminacy in the inner source of thought and experience and indeterminacy in the outer physics, so experience is sandwiched between indeterminacies: the 3rd substance of neutral monism or double-aspect theory.

I consider it unplausible and unconvincing that solipsists do not act and behave as solipsists in their daily life. Solipsism is only an interesting game of thoughts.

If they did act like solipsists, everyone else would clash with them pretty quickly. They are probably smart enough not to.
